# vb.net mySql Datagridview refresh problems

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Recently i was trying to display data on datagridview but every time there is a new entry the DGV (datagridview) was not refreshing. I made a new method called showtable but when i search i use to get the database names insted of moded names in the code for example tax to TAX and so on.. 
This is the code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    konekcija = New MySqlConnection
    konekcija.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=baza"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        Dim kupovnacena As Double
        Dim prodaznacena As Double

        kupovnacena = TextBoxKupovna.Text
        prodaznacena = TextBoxProdazna.Text
        If kupovnacena > prodaznacena Then
            MessageBox.Show("Продажната цена не може да биде помала од куповната !")
            TextBoxKupovna.Text = ""
            TextBoxProdazna.Text = ""
        End If

        konekcija.Open()
        If TextBoxBarkod.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Внеси баркод/шифра")
        End If
        If TextBoxNaziv.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Внеси назив на артиклот")
        End If
        If TextBoxKupovna.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Внеси куповна цена на артиклот")
        End If
        If TextBoxProdazna.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Внеси продажна цена на артиклот")
            TextBoxProdazna.Text = Focus()
        End If
        Dim Query As String
       Query = "insert into baza.artikli(id,barkod,naziv,kupovna,prodazna,opis,kolicina,proizvoditel,ddv,makpr) values ('" & TextBoxID.Text & "','" & TextBoxBarkod.Text & "','" & TextBoxNaziv.Text & "','" & TextBoxKupovna.Text & "','" & TextBoxProdazna.Text & "','" & TextBoxOpis.Text & "','" & TextBoxKolicina.Text & "','" & TextBoxProiz.Text & "','" & ddv & "','" & makpr & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader


        MessageBox.Show("Артиклот е успешно ажуриран !")
        TextBoxBarkod.Text = ""
        TextBoxKupovna.Text = ""
        TextBoxNaziv.Text = ""
        TextBoxOpis.Text = ""
        TextBoxProdazna.Text = ""
        TextBoxKolicina.Text = ""
        TextBoxID.Text = ""
        TextBoxProiz.Text = ""
        konekcija.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        konekcija.Dispose()
        datagridview1.refresh()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: `READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader` doesnt  do anything with the data.  How does the DGV get its data, is it bound?

Comment: its getting it thorung visual studio bata connector